# Inserting data from one database to another database in specific columns not working

Tags: mysql, migration, phpmyadmin

I have `csv` formatted data, i want to put the data to my existing database's table in specific columns. I was trying to do it with `LOAD DATA INFILE...` and i have even uncomment the `mysqli.allow_local_infile` but still I'm getting the same error

> load data local infile is forbidden check mysqli.allow_local_infile

Then, i thought to do it in another way, I just created a new database named `staging_hadiths` and created only those columns which are ibn my `CSV file`, and uploaded my CSV to that database. Now, I was trying to copy that database's table data to my `real database table` in specific columns like this:

```
SELECT hadithUrdu, urduNarrator from staging_hadiths.hadiths;
UPDATE ifislam_hadiths.hadiths SET hadithUrdu=staging_hadiths.hadiths.hadithUrdu AND urduNarrator=staging_hadiths.hadiths.urduNarrator WHERE hadithNumber BETWEEN 3949 AND 4977
```

but i got an error:
[image]

**Data is too large, I can't put data one by one in database. I hope you people will help me.**
I have to use `where between for some reasons`, so the data can insert to my real database's table in the right order.
**My staging database:**
[image]


**My real database:**
[image]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update a table with data from another table, you have to join the tables.  In your case, if staging "hadiths" contains only a single row, you could leave out the join, as follows:

```
UPDATE ifislam_hadiths.hadiths h1
inner join staging_hadiths.hadiths h2
SET h1.hadithUrdu = h2.hadithUrdu, -- AND does not comply with mysql syntax
    h1.urduNarrator = h2.hadiths.urduNarrator
WHERE h1.hadithNumber BETWEEN 3949 AND 4977
```

But normally you would join the two tables so that each row from the table to be updated, corresponds to a single row from the other table.

An example from [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/updating-a-mysql-table-with-values-from-another-table)